# Authentication set is not working in cakephp 3.x unit test case

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

Here I am writing the test cases for changes password in cakephp 3.x, for that I have set the session for authentication check in test cases, but it is not working.

My code is

```
public function setUserSession() {
    $auth = [
        'Auth' => [
            'user' => [
                'id' => 2,
                'email' => 'testemail1@test.ie',
                'firstname' => 'testfastname',
                'lastname' => 'testlastname',
                'gender' => 'male',
                'active' => 1,
                'created' => '2016-02-19 11:54:47',
                'modified' => '2016-02-19 11:54:47'
            ]
        ]
    ];
    return $auth;
}
 /**
 * Test register method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testpassword()
{


   $data = [ 
        'current_password' => '123456',
        'new_password'=>'12345678',
        'repeat_password'=>'12345678',
    ];
   $this->session($this->setUserSession());

   $this->post('/Customers/password', $data);

   $this->assertResponseSuccess();
    //echo "Ser"; exit;
   // $users = TableRegistry::get('customers');
    //$query = $users->find()->where(['email' => $data['email']]);
    //$this->assertEquals(1, $query->count());

}
```

And checking in customer controller like this but is not working.

```
   $id = $this->Auth->user('id');

    if (!$this->Customers->exists(['id' => $id])) {
        $this->Flash->error('You have been logged out');
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
    }
```

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Please be more specific as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead. Also show your debugging attempts.

Comment: Looks like `user` isn't capitalized in your session key.